# How can I convert the qblast XML output into the NCBI BLAST -outfmt 17?

Tags: format, biopython, blast

I started my project with the NCBI standalone BLAST and used the -outfmt 17 option. For my purpose that formatting is extremely helpful. However, I had to change to Biopython and I'm now using qblast to align my sequences to the NCBI NT database. Can I save/convert the qblast XML in a format which is comparable to the NCBI BLAST standalone -outfmt 17 format?

Thank you very much for your help!

Cheers, 
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you meant `-outfmt 7` and you need an output with columns.

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW, NCBIXML

# This is the BLASTN query which returns an XML handler in a StringIO
r = NCBIWWW.qblast(
    "blastn",
    "nr",
    "ACGGGGTCTCGAAAAAAGGAGAATGGGATGAGAAGGATATATGGGTAGTGTCATTTTTTAACTTGCAGAT" +
    "TTCATCCTAGTCTTCCAGTTATCGTTTCCTAGCACTCCATGTTCCCAAGATAGTGTCACCACCCCAAGGA" +
    "CTCTCTCTCATTTTCTTTGCCTGGGCCCTCTTTCTACTGAGGAGTCGTGGCCTTCCATCAGTAGAAGCCG",
    expect=1E-5)

# Now we read that XML extracting the info

for record in NCBIXML.parse(r):
    for alignment in record.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            cols = "{}\t" * 10
            print(cols.format(hsp.positives / hsp.align_length,
                              hsp.align_length,
                              hsp.align_length - hsp.positives,
                              hsp.gaps,
                              hsp.query_start,
                              hsp.query_end,
                              hsp.sbjct_start,
                              hsp.sbjct_end,
                              hsp.expect,
                              hsp.score))
```

Outputs something like:

```
1   210 0   0   1   210 89250   89459   8.73028e-102    420.0   
0   206 19  2   5   210 46259   46462   5.16461e-73 314.0   
1   210 0   0   1   210 68822   69031   8.73028e-102    420.0   
0   206 19  2   5   210 25825   26028   5.16461e-73 314.0   
1   210 0   0   1   210 65887   66096   8.73028e-102    420.0   
...
```

Comment: Actually I meant -outfmt 17 :) But anyway your answer is extremely helpful. I'll try to code a parser for my needs. I'm new to coding so that might take a while but hopefully it will work.

Thank you!

Comment: My BLAST only have outfmt until 11, If you provide a sample of the output I'll update my answer. If you think my answer works for your question you should accept it.

Comment: I don't know why but I have a few more outfmt options. Here is how the outfmt 17 output looks like:
KC262216.1 0 Query_1 1 255 8199H713M10H * 0 0 * * AS:i:713 EV:f:0 NM:i:0 PI:f:100.00 BS:f:1317.78

Anyway I adapted your code above to transfer the data into a format that I can use. It's not outfmt 17 but one step further in my data processing. Thanks again for your help